# Ошибка python при запуске программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Вроде делаю все правильно, но почему кидает ексепшен, по всей видимости не хватает зависимостей, но каких?

Ниже собственно код

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, square
from numpy.linalg import inv
from numpy.random import rand


def generate_signal(f, N, t=(0, 10, 100)):
    """
    f - function to generate
    N - number of points
    """
    x = np.linspace(*t)
    dx = np.linspace(t[0], t[1], N)
    signal = f(x)
    d_signal = f(dx)
    return x, dx, signal, d_signal


def gram_schmidt(A):
    """
    A - matrix
    """

    def proj(a, b):
        return (np.sum(a * b) / np.sum(b * b)) * b

    Z = A.copy()
    for i in range(1, len(Z)):
        s = [proj(Z[i], Z[j]) for j in range(i)]
        s = np.sum(s, axis=0)
        Z[i] -= np.array(s).ravel()
        del s
    return Z.round(3)


def normalize(A):
    Z = A.copy()
    for i in range(len(Z)):
        s = Z[i]
        n = sqrt(sum(square(Z[i])))
        Z[i] /= n
    return Z.round(3)


def change_basis(E, G, x):
    """
    E - old basis
    G - new basis
    x - vector in E
    return - x in G
    """
    C = np.dot(inv(E), G)
    return np.dot(inv(C), x)


N = 3
# Базис
A = np.zeros((N, N))
np.fill_diagonal(A, 1)

signal = (0.5, 0.2, 0.7)

B = np.array([[0.3, 0.9, 0.8],
              [0.5, 0.2, 0.5],
              [0.8, 0.7, 0.5]])

# Не ноль, вектора образуют бизис
np.linalg.det(B).round(3)

# Представление сигнала signal в базисе B
signal_b = change_basis(A, B, signal)

# Убедимся, что переход из базиса в базис работает. Вернем сигнал обратно в базис A
change_basis(B, A, signal_b)

# Ортогональная система
C = gram_schmidt(B)
# Сигнал в базисе C
signal_c = change_basis(A, C, signal)

for i in range(N - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        print('{:.2f}'.format(sum(C[i] * C[j])))

# Вернемся из C в A (порядок)
change_basis(C, A, signal_c)

Cn = normalize(C)
signal_cn = change_basis(C, Cn, signal_c)

# Разложение исходного сигнала в базисе А
xa = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A.transpose()), signal).round(3)
print(xa)

xb = np.dot(inv(B.transpose()), signal_b).round(3)
print(xb)

# Разложение сигнала c в базисе C
xc = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(C.transpose()), signal_c).round(3)
print(xc)

# Разложение сигнала cn в базисе Cn (нормированном)
xcn = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Cn.transpose()), signal_cn).round(3)
print(xcn)


def fourier_coeff(B, signal):
    C = np.array([(B[i] * signal).sum() / square(sqrt(square(B[i]).sum())) for i in range(N)])
    return C


Ca = fourier_coeff(A, signal).round(3)
print('Коэффициенты Фурье в А \n {}'.format(Ca))
Cb = fourier_coeff(B, signal_b).round(3)
print('Коэффициенты Фурье в B \n {}'.format(Cb))
Cc = fourier_coeff(C, signal_c).round(3)
print('Коэффициенты Фурье в C \n {}'.format(Cc))
Ccn = fourier_coeff(Cn, signal_cn).round(3)
print('Коэффициенты Фурье в C нормированном \n {}'.format(Ccn))

print("{:.3f} <= {:.3f}".format(square(Ca).sum(), square(sqrt(sum(square(xa))))))

# Это конечно выглядит странно, но формально выполняется
print("{:.3f} <= {:.3f}".format(square(Cb).sum(), square(sqrt(sum(square(xb))))))

print("{:.3f} <= {:.3f}".format(square(Cc).sum(), square(sqrt(sum(square(xc))))))

print("{:.3f} <= {:.3f}".format(square(Ccn).sum(), square(sqrt(sum(square(xcn))))))

# Воостановили сигнал в C по коэффициенетам Фурье
f = np.array(C.transpose() * Cc).sum(axis=1)

# Восстановим сигнал в базисе A, получим изначальный сигнал
appr_a = change_basis(C, A, f)

N = 20

x, dx, signal, d_signal = generate_signal(lambda x: 0.8 * np.sin(x) + np.cos(0.2 * x), N)

A = np.zeros((N, N))
np.fill_diagonal(A, 1)

B = rand(N, N)

np.linalg.det(B).round(3)

signal_b = change_basis(A, B, d_signal)

C = gram_schmidt(B)
signal_c = change_basis(A, C, d_signal)

Cn = normalize(C)
signal_cn = change_basis(C, Cn, signal_c)

xa = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A.transpose()), d_signal).round(3)
print(xa)

xb = np.dot(inv(B.transpose()), signal_b).round(3)
print(xb)

xc = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(C.transpose()), signal_c).round(3)
print(xc)

xcn = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Cn.transpose()), signal_cn).round(3)
print(xcn)

Ca = fourier_coeff(A, d_signal).round(3)
Cb = fourier_coeff(B, signal_b).round(3)
Cc = fourier_coeff(C, signal_c).round(3)
Ccn = fourier_coeff(Cn, signal_cn).round(3)

f = np.array(Cn.transpose() * Ccn).sum(axis=1)

appr_a = change_basis(Cn, A, f)
```

**Сам ексепшен:**

```
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\gibki\PycharmProjects\lab1\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\gibki\PycharmProjects\lab1\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
-0.00
-0.00
0.00
[0.5 0.2 0.7]
[-0.37  -2.275  2.15 ]
[0.326 1.028 4.652]
[0.501 0.2   0.701]
Коэффициенты Фурье в А 
 [0.5 0.2 0.7]
Коэффициенты Фурье в B 
 [0.325 0.37  0.507]
Коэффициенты Фурье в C 
 [0.325 1.029 4.651]
Коэффициенты Фурье в C нормированном 
 [0.5 0.2 0.7]
0.780 <= 0.780
0.500 <= 9.935
22.796 <= 22.804
0.780 <= 0.782
[ 1.     1.396  1.673  1.751  1.601  1.255  0.794  0.327 -0.035 -0.216
 -0.186  0.022  0.329  0.625  0.804  0.791  0.562  0.151 -0.357 -0.851]
[-2.408  3.628 -3.886 -4.228  4.943  0.918  3.833  6.117 -4.543  5.869
  0.116 -1.725 -1.004 -3.206  9.499  4.55   3.648 -0.748 -9.821 -5.881]
[  0.151   0.357   0.948   0.855   1.257   1.472   0.626   0.192  -0.037
  -0.186  -0.159   0.018   0.415   1.111   2.57    1.294   1.885   0.259
  -5.89  -10.027]
[ 0.997  1.394  1.673  1.752  1.604  1.254  0.795  0.33  -0.035 -0.215
 -0.188  0.023  0.326  0.622  0.804  0.792  0.567  0.152 -0.362 -0.854]
```

Comment: вы указали не полный `error traceback`. Какая строка вашего кода вызывает ошибку?

Comment: @MaxU если бы я знал какая строка кода дает ошибку я бы не задавал вопрос. я программист джава, питон для меня это нечто новое. но тут я подозреваю проблема в зависимостях

Comment: Это не поъоже на __полный__  error traceback...

Comment: @MaxU а где мне полный взять?

Comment: как вы запускали ваш скрипт?

Comment: @MaxU ctrl + shift+f10

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85551/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Comment: если нужен будет ответ, напишите мне . скину ответ на мой вопрос